# Kubernetes HPA change polling interval

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, datadog, hpa

I use Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with `External` metric based on a value provided by DataDog agent

```yaml
apiVersion: datadoghq.com/v1alpha1
kind: DatadogMetric
metadata:
  name: queue-size
spec:
  query: "max:redis.key.length{key:my-tasks}.fill(zero)"
```

Corresponding HPA configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: celery-worker
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metric:
        name: "datadogmetric@default:queue-size"
```

I want workers to be scaled almost immediately as queue grows, so need polling period to be at most `2-5` seconds. By default it's 30 seconds ([as per docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/cluster_agent/external_metrics/?tab=helm#example-hpa))

[image]

How do I change poll interval on k8s side? Is there a flag when configuring HPA or should I tune DataDog agent instead?

Answer (score 4):

Kubernetes implements horizontal pod autoscaling as a control loop that runs intermittently (it is not a continuous process). The interval is set by the ***--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period*** parameter to the **kube-controller-manager** (and the default interval is 15 seconds). You should tweak the value as per your requirement

Comment: Please share a link to the docs or the exact place where I should put this flag

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/